# What is the nature of the network traffic I see on bootup?

Tags: traffic, privacy

Linux Mint 19 (cinnamon)

On boot up I see connections to the following:

1. golem.canonical.com and pugot.canonical.com
2. all-systems.mcast.net and igmp.mcast.net
3. 224.0.0.251 (multicast, is this local?)
4. 151.101.18.217 (resolves as fastly.com) - TCP and TLSv2, seems to start with Mint Update Manager
5. 80.3.197.104.bc.googleusercontent.com - TCP and HTTP, occurring a few minutes after logon (probably not exclusively then)
6. 171.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com

I guess 1. 2. and 3. are to do with system updates, and should be of no concern to me, but what are 4. and particularly 5. and 6. doing?

I'm coming at this from a privacy angle, but also with a wish to minimise traffic as I will be on a low data allowance connection at times.

Some programs accessing the network interface, not sure which connections these correspond with at the moment:

- flatpak
- usr/bin/python3
- usr/sbin/NetworkManager

Part 2.

Additionally with System Monitor, vnstat etc, I see a sort of pulse every second of 50bits or so. I have since realised (via Wireshark) that this is Scanning Tree Protocol (and presumably just local traffic between my laptop and router) which will not presumably impact on my ISP allowance, but is there any way I can exclude this data from the vnstat feed I use in Conky on my desktop, so that I see the true data use which matches what my ISP will be charging me for?

Comment: Into what stage did you get these network activity? From the Power On till the logon prompt?

Comment: Thanks, information added above. All connections are after logon, not sure how to monitor these things before logon?

Answer (score 0):

1. is going to be NTP times, and system updates check-in / phone-homes... Other distros do it too, and it can be disabled if you like. This stems from prior research and see the following for reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/617737/ubuntu-14-04-spying-suspicious-traffic-at-boot
2. is standard multicast network chatter, lots of devices do it.
3. more multicast stuff, and likely no worries here.
4. I am not sure about this, because I have not experienced it (yet).

However,
5 and 6 are what I want to focus on. I too am wondering about what they are and why the native program NetworkManager is calling out to them. If you use a program called nethogs you can find the program thats making the traffic. Once you have nethogs, use:

```
nethogs -d 1
```

I have searched in various locations for the NetworkManager configs but so far nothing.

Regarding this, See  https://superuser.com/questions/1446752/fresh-install-linux-mint-has-random-connections-to-google